# Добавить цену рассрочки для Woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Хочу добавить поле цены рассрочки для сайта Wordpress (Woocomerce). По простой формуле цена/12. Имеются ли какие нибудь плагины или надо создать код и вставить в woocomerce
[image: пример]

Comment: А в чём собственно проблема (кроме 67% переплаты за год по такой _"рассрочке"_)?

Comment: Учись пользоваться репо https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/installment/.  И не нужно ставить лишних тегов.